# Acesso ao banco de dados Entity Framework

Tags: .net, entity-framework

Peguei uma aplicação em C# .NET desenvolvido com Entity Framework, porém não consigo acessar o banco de dados, com a seguinte mensagem:

> The underlying pdovider failed to Open.

Possuo somente a aplicação, porém nenhum banco de dados local ou remoto, teria como exportar a modelagem do Entity Framework na aplicação para o SQL Express/Server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você vai precisar de um banco de dados.

O EF tem a opção de Code-First que cria a base de dados para você.

Dá uma lida..

http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/database-initialization-strategy-in-code-first.aspx

Abs